# error using newenvironments with parameters

Tags: macros, environments

I'm pretty new to latex and I'm trying to create a format for exam questions that would make write as few latex as possible. For the moment I wrote this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\newcounter{answerCounter}
\setcounter{answerCounter}{0}


%the question environment wrapping every exam questions
\newenvironment{qst}[2]{
        \setcounter{answerCounter}{0}
        \item q#1 : #2 %the first argument of q is the question number
        \begin{itemize}
}{ \end{itemize} }

\newcommand{answ}[1]{
        \item a\value{answerCounter}: #1
        \addtocounter{answerCounter}{1}
}


\begin{itemize}
        \begin{qst}{1}{to be or not to be?}
                \answ{to be}
                \answ{not to be}
        \end{qst}

        \begin{qst}{2}{are you john doe?}
            \answ{No i'm Chuck Norris}
            \answ{maybe}
            \answ{yes}
        \end{qst}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

and I want it to display this:

[image]

the sample of errors I get is the following:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   s
l.20 }

? 
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.20 }
...
```

What could help reduce the number of errors to zero?

Comment: There are packages like `exsheets` that can do that already. No need to reinvent the wheel. ;-)

Comment: It needs to be something like `\newcommand{\answ}[1]{\item a\alph{answerCounter}: #1 \refstepcounter{answerCounter}}` or `\newcommand{\answ}[1]{\item \refstepcounter{answerCounter}a\theanswerCounter: #1 }`

Comment: thank you putting \the in front of answerCounter worked wonders, is there more documentation about \the usage?

Comment: @Simonlbc: The `\the.....` is a basic feature and documented in basically any introduction to LaTeX ;-)  Each LaTeX counter has a `\the....` command associated to it and is defined automatically as soon as `\newcounter{...}` is applied, by default `\thefoo` it is the same as `\arabic{foo}`

Comment: @Simonlbc: Depending on your intentions you will have to use `\refstepcounter` if you plan references to your 'items'

Comment: Thank you @ChristianHupfer! What do you mean by "plan references to your 'items'" though?

Comment: If you want to have *See answer 5b*.

Comment: @Simonlbc: Something like `In Answer \ref{foo:stuff}` we have seen etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the missing backslash in `\newcommand{answ}`.

Also `\value{answerCounter}` is wrong: you want a printed representation, so `\theanswerCounter` is what you need. Also, the counter should be initialized to 1, rather than 0.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{answerCounter}

%the question environment wrapping every exam questions
\newenvironment{qst}[2]
 {\setcounter{answerCounter}{1}%
  \item q#1: #2% the first argument of q is the question number
  \begin{itemize}
 }
 {\end{itemize}}

\newcommand{\answ}[1]{%
  \item a\theanswerCounter: #1%
  \stepcounter{answerCounter}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\begin{qst}{1}{to be or not to be?}
  \answ{to be}
  \answ{not to be}
\end{qst}

\begin{qst}{2}{are you john doe?}
  \answ{No i'm Chuck Norris}
  \answ{maybe}
  \answ{yes}
\end{qst}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]